# Compiling libnoise on OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, noise, libtool, libtool-xcode

Has anyone compiled, or know of a pre-compiled, [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/) for MacOS X 10.6? It does not compile out of the box here due to a libtool issue.

```
libtool --mode=compile g++   -c ../src/latlon.cpp -o ../src/latlon.o
libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --mode=compile
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because OS X has its own `libtool`, quite different from GNU's `libtool`, which is called `glibtool` on OS X.  You need to edit `Makefile` in `src/` to set

```
LIBTOOL = glibtool
```

etc. You should also delete the lines which generates `.so` files, because OS X has a different format for the dynamic library and how it is installed. I'd recommend you to stick to `.a` file. Good luck!

This Apple document [Porting UNIX/Linux Applications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/intro/intro.html) might help you.